# KeyError1 in the code to compare values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare the below list of lists and declare one as greater than other based on the value it returns. It gets complied successfully on an online complier (repl.it) but giving the weird error KeyError1  for some reason. Please help .

```
stats = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '0']]
    stats1 = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '1']]
    for s1, s2 in zip(stats, stats1):
        if s1[1] < s2[1]:
            print ('success')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], including the full error you see.

Comment: your code is fine, its probably the indentation error + the `print()` should be a function in python 3

Comment: Fixing the indentation error doesn't generate a `KeyError`. This code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
stats = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '0']]
stats1 = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '1']]

if any(any(a > b for a, b in zip(i, c)) for i, c in zip(stats, stats1)):
     print("success")
```